# National Rail SOAP XML API call via Postman

Tags: xml, api, soap

Trying to make a call with Postman to National Rail API using SOAP XML, but getting a "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials" response. Here is what I have:

Address Bar

```
POST https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb10.asmx
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2017-02-02/ldb/GetDepartureBoard
Accept-encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate, x-bzip2
```

Body:

```
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:ldb="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2017-02-02/ldb/"
  xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
  xmlns:typ="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2017-02-02/Token/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <typ:AccessToken>
      <typ:TokenValue>**** token removed ****</typ:TokenValue>
    </typ:AccessToken>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ldb:GetDepartureBoardRequest>
      <ldb:crs>LST</ldb:crs>
      <ldb:numRows>10</ldb:numRows>
      <ldb:timeOffset>0</ldb:timeOffset>
      <ldb:timeWindow>120</ldb:timeWindow>
    </ldb:GetDepartureBoardRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Some documentation is here: https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/openldbws/

Example call here: http://nrodwiki.rockshore.net/index.php/GetDepBoardWithDetails

Any assistance would be appreciated - I want to understand how to correctly make the API call so I can progress with my hobby project app.

Answer (score 1):

Change the address to :

```
https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb9.asmx
```

Change the soap: Envelope

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
 xmlns:typ="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2013-11-28/Token/types"
 xmlns:ldb="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2016-02-16/ldb/">
```

If you use a valid token this will work (I've tested in Postman).

Hope that helps.